# Does sitecore send mail function (Sitecore.MainUtil.SendMail) has create log message event?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Does anyone know 
Sitecore `Sitecore.MainUtil.SendMail` function has standard functionality to write log about  about sent mail?
Is it possible to switch it on?
or do I need use my custom log for it?

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **Sitecore 6.6 update 4** `SendMail` function looks like this:

```
public static void SendMail(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message)
{
  string mailServer = Settings.MailServer;
  SmtpClient smtpClient;
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailServer))
  {
    smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
  }
  else
  {
    int mailServerPort = Settings.MailServerPort;
    smtpClient = mailServerPort <= 0 ? new SmtpClient(mailServer) : new SmtpClient(mailServer, mailServerPort);
  }
  string mailServerUserName = Settings.MailServerUserName;
  if (mailServerUserName.Length > 0)
  {
    string mailServerPassword = Settings.MailServerPassword;
    NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(mailServerUserName, mailServerPassword);
    smtpClient.Credentials = (ICredentialsByHost) networkCredential;
  }
  smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

It doesn't contain and log functionality, so you need to add it on your own if you need it.